# Return custom jsp from controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, model-view-controller

I need to implement a controller using Spring so that it sets appropriate jsp in ModelAndView object.

Let's put it that way. I made an API call to a server and got the order in which I need to render my View(like TitleView -> PriceView -> ReviewView). So I need to set view object which will follow that order. It may possible that api returns next order which is different from the previous one, in that situation it should set view object accordingly.

**Note:- We are storing jsp for each component like Title, Price, Review somewhere in project directory.**

```
@GetMapping("/product")
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView process(@RequestParam...) {
    // Getting order as string from API
    List<String> order = api.getOrder(...);

    // business logic

    ContentModelAndView mav = new ContentModelAndView();
    mav.addObject("obj", obj);
    mav.setViewName(???)
    // what should be the logic to setViewName so that we dynamically set the order.
    return mav;
}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: You want a JSP but still use `@ResponseBody` that isn't going to work. Also what you want is just a simple view which renders parts in your view. So viewname will always be the same, you want to control the content of your page.

Comment: @m-deinum so what is the suggested way to do it. I just want that a modelAndView object is returned where view will be segregation of static jsp(like title, price,...). Order of that jsp should change in accordance to API response. If you could give more insights it would be great.

Comment: I would suggest to create a common JSP page. Pass a order of the view (could be a array) through model attribute. According to the order array, check which page you need to show and only load that page specific attributes on the view.